# Adding new coordinate on same form

Tags: c#, winforms

My code paints a circle on Form 2 when coordinates of circles are entered in textboxes in form 1 and button is clicked. The problem is, every time the coordinates are entered in Form 1, A new Form 2 is opening rather than old one getting updated.

Code on 1st Form

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int r1, r2;
    setValue = textBox1.Text;
    setValue1 = textBox2.Text;
    Int32.TryParse(setValue, out r1);
    Int32.TryParse(setValue1, out r2);
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    //// f2.Show();
    // f2.addcoordinate(r1,r2);
    // f2.Update();
    Graphics g2;
    g2 = f2.CreateGraphics();
    Class1 add = new Class1();
    add.addcoordinate(r1,r2);
}
```

Code in Class1

```
public void addcoordinate(int r1, int r2)
{
   // MessageBox.Show(r1.ToString());
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.addcoordinate(r1, r2);
    f2.Show();
}
```

Code on Form2

```
private List<Point> circleCoordinates = new List<Point>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void addcoordinate(int r1, int r2)
{
    this.circleCoordinates.Add(new Point(r1, r2));
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // linedrawing goes here
    foreach (Point point in this.circleCoordinates)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(point, new 
        Size(10, 10)));
    }

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Store a reference to your Form2 object somewhere and use it instead of creating a new one every time.

Comment: `Form2 f2 = new Form2();` creates a new copy of the form every time you run it. Instead create one copy, and re-use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Form1` you defined `f2` as follows:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
```

Every time this line of code is run, it creates a new instance of the object. That's why you see a new form each time you click on your button.

Define the `Form2` object inside the `Form1` class and  out of all the private methods by moving the above mentioned line of code outside the methods in the class. Then use the specific instance of `Form2` that you have declared (`f2` in this case), in the code inside your methods. This way, you are working on the same instance of the class and you are not creating new instances of the object `Form2` every time you click on `button1`.

Comment: `f2 = new Form2();` still re-initialises the variable with a new instance of the Form. All you've changed is where the variable is declared. The code needs to operate on the existing instance of the form, not a new one

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @ADyson . I edited the answer.

Comment: Further, I want to draw the circles on the chosen coordinates with increasing radius in a small time interval. Please suggest how to do it.